# PDF - barcode printing is always failing with TCPDF

Tags: php, barcode, tcpdf, barcode-printing

I am always getting:

> TCPDF ERROR: Error in 1D barcode string

On

```
public function testingAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
    $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 027');
    $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 027', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // set a barcode on the page footer
    $pdf->setBarcode(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    // set font
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11);

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // print a message
    $txt = "You can also export 1D barcodes in other formats (PNG, SVG, HTML). Check the examples inside the barcodes directory.\n";
    $pdf->MultiCell(70, 50, $txt, 0, 'J', false, 1, 125, 30, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
    $pdf->SetY(30);

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

    // define barcode style
    $style = array(
        'position' => '',
        'align' => 'C',
        'stretch' => false,
        'fitwidth' => true,
        'cellfitalign' => '',
        'border' => true,
        'hpadding' => 'auto',
        'vpadding' => 'auto',
        'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
        'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255),
        'text' => true,
        'font' => 'helvetica',
        'fontsize' => 8,
        'stretchtext' => 4
    );

    // PRINT VARIOUS 1D BARCODES

    // CODE 39 - ANSI MH10.8M-1983 - USD-3 - 3 of 9.
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 39 - ANSI MH10.8M-1983 - USD-3 - 3 of 9', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('CODE 39', 'C39', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // CODE 39 + CHECKSUM
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 39 + CHECKSUM', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('CODE 39 +', 'C39+', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // CODE 39 EXTENDED
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 39 EXTENDED', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('CODE 39 E', 'C39E', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // CODE 39 EXTENDED + CHECKSUM
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 39 EXTENDED + CHECKSUM', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('CODE 39 E+', 'C39E+', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // CODE 93 - USS-93
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 93 - USS-93', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('TEST93', 'C93', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // Standard 2 of 5
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'Standard 2 of 5', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('1234567', 'S25', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // Standard 2 of 5 + CHECKSUM
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'Standard 2 of 5 + CHECKSUM', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('1234567', 'S25+', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // Interleaved 2 of 5
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'Interleaved 2 of 5', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('1234567', 'I25', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // Interleaved 2 of 5 + CHECKSUM
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'Interleaved 2 of 5 + CHECKSUM', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('1234567', 'I25+', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');


    // add a page ----------
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // CODE 128 AUTO
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 128 AUTO', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('CODE 128 AUTO', 'C128', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // CODE 128 A
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 128 A', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('CODE 128 A', 'C128A', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // CODE 128 B
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 128 B', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('CODE 128 B', 'C128B', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // CODE 128 C
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 128 C', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('0123456789', 'C128C', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // EAN 8
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'EAN 8', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('1234567', 'EAN8', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // EAN 13
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'EAN 13', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('1234567890128', 'EAN13', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // UPC-A
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'UPC-A', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('12345678901', 'UPCA', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // UPC-E
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'UPC-E', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('04210000526', 'UPCE', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    // add a page ----------
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // 5-Digits UPC-Based Extension
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, '5-Digits UPC-Based Extension', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('51234', 'EAN5', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // 2-Digits UPC-Based Extension
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, '2-Digits UPC-Based Extension', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('34', 'EAN2', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // MSI
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'MSI', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('80523', 'MSI', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // MSI + CHECKSUM (module 11)
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'MSI + CHECKSUM (module 11)', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('80523', 'MSI+', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // CODABAR
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODABAR', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('123456789', 'CODABAR', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // CODE 11
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 11', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('123-456-789', 'CODE11', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // PHARMACODE
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'PHARMACODE', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('789', 'PHARMA', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // PHARMACODE TWO-TRACKS
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'PHARMACODE TWO-TRACKS', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('105', 'PHARMA2T', '', '', '', 18, 2, $style, 'N');

    // add a page ----------
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // IMB - Intelligent Mail Barcode - Onecode - USPS-B-3200
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'IMB - Intelligent Mail Barcode - Onecode - USPS-B-3200', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('01234567094987654321-01234567891', 'IMB', '', '', '', 15, 0.6, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // POSTNET
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'POSTNET', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('98000', 'POSTNET', '', '', '', 15, 0.6, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // PLANET
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'PLANET', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('98000', 'PLANET', '', '', '', 15, 0.6, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // RMS4CC (Royal Mail 4-state Customer Code) - CBC (Customer Bar Code)
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'RMS4CC (Royal Mail 4-state Customer Code) - CBC (Customer Bar Code)', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('SN34RD1A', 'RMS4CC', '', '', '', 15, 0.6, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln();

    // KIX (Klant index - Customer index)
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'KIX (Klant index - Customer index)', 0, 1);
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('SN34RDX1A', 'KIX', '', '', '', 15, 0.6, $style, 'N');

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    // TEST BARCODE ALIGNMENTS

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // set a background color
    $style['bgcolor'] = array(255,255,240);
    $style['fgcolor'] = array(127,0,0);

    // Left position
    $style['position'] = 'L';
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('LEFT', 'C128A', '', '', '', 15, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln(2);

    // Center position
    $style['position'] = 'C';
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('CENTER', 'C128A', '', '', '', 15, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln(2);

    // Right position
    $style['position'] = 'R';
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('RIGHT', 'C128A', '', '', '', 15, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln(2);
    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

    $style['fgcolor'] = array(0,127,0);
    $style['position'] = '';
    $style['stretch'] = false; // disable stretch
    $style['fitwidth'] = false; // disable fitwidth

    // Left alignment
    $style['align'] = 'L';
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('LEFT', 'C128A', '', '', '', 15, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln(2);

    // Center alignment
    $style['align'] = 'C';
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('CENTER', 'C128A', '', '', '', 15, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln(2);

    // Right alignment
    $style['align'] = 'R';
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('RIGHT', 'C128A', '', '', '', 15, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln(2);
    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

    $style['fgcolor'] = array(0,64,127);
    $style['position'] = '';
    $style['stretch'] = false; // disable stretch
    $style['fitwidth'] = true; // disable fitwidth

    // Left alignment
    $style['cellfitalign'] = 'L';
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('LEFT', 'C128A', 105, '', 90, 15, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln(2);

    // Center alignment
    $style['cellfitalign'] = 'C';
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('CENTER', 'C128A', 105, '', 90, 15, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln(2);

    // Right alignment
    $style['cellfitalign'] = 'R';
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('RIGHT', 'C128A', 105, '', 90, 15, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln(2);
    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

    $style['fgcolor'] = array(127,0,127);

    // Left alignment
    $style['position'] = 'L';
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('LEFT', 'C128A', '', '', '', 15, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln(2);

    // Center alignment
    $style['position'] = 'C';
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('CENTER', 'C128A', '', '', '', 15, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    $pdf->Ln(2);

    // Right alignment
    $style['position'] = 'R';
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('RIGHT', 'C128A', '', '', '', 15, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    // TEST BARCODE STYLE

    // define barcode style
    $style = array(
        'position' => '',
        'align' => '',
        'stretch' => true,
        'fitwidth' => false,
        'cellfitalign' => '',
        'border' => true,
        'hpadding' => 'auto',
        'vpadding' => 'auto',
        'fgcolor' => array(0,0,128),
        'bgcolor' => array(255,255,128),
        'text' => true,
        'label' => 'CUSTOM LABEL',
        'font' => 'helvetica',
        'fontsize' => 8,
        'stretchtext' => 4
    );

    // CODE 39 EXTENDED + CHECKSUM
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 39 EXTENDED + CHECKSUM', 0, 1);
    $pdf->SetLineStyle(array('width' => 1, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(255, 0, 0)));
    $pdf->write1DBarcode('CODE 39 E+', 'C39E+', '', '', 120, 25, 0.4, $style, 'N');

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    //Close and output PDF document
    $pdf->Output('example_027.pdf', 'I');
  }
```

Could somebody please help me with this?

**EDIT: working**

---

```
  public function apprintAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);      

    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    //set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    //$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);


    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
    $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 8, '', true);
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);

    // Connect to DataBase
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', 'production');
    $db = Zend_Db::factory($config->resources->db);

    $kiosk = $_GET['kiosk'];
    $sql = "select *from table0 where kiosk='{$kiosk}' and task='print' order by id desc limit 1";
    $result = $db->fetchAll($sql);
    if(count($result) > 0 ){
      $qr_code = '';
      // Collect the QR code here
      $sql = "select *from table1 where rrn='{$result[0]['rrn']}' and firstname='{$result[0]['firstname']}' and lastname='{$result[0]['lastname']}' order by id desc limit 1";

      $result1 = $db->fetchAll($sql);   
      if(count($result1)> 0) {
        $qr_code = $result1[0]['picture'];
      }

      $gape = 20;
      $width = 30;

      $sql = "select *from table2 where rd='{$result[0]['rrn']}'";
      $result2 = $db->fetchAll($sql);
      if(count($result2)>0) {
        foreach($result2 as $k=>$v) {
          $pdf->AddPage();
          $img_file = APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/fpdi/en.jpg';
          $pdf->Image($img_file, 0, -10, 190, 300, '', '', '', true, 300, 'C', false, false, 0);   

          $pdf->writeHTMLCell(80, '', 78, 25, $result2[$k]['e'], 1, 0, 1, true, 'J', true);
          $pdf->writeHTMLCell(80, '', 78, 55, $result2[$k]['d'], 1, 0, 1, true, 'J', true);
          $pdf->writeHTMLCell(80, '', 78, 65, $result2[$k]['c'], 1, 0, 1, true, 'J', true);
          $pdf->writeHTMLCell(80, '', 78, 74, $result2[$k]['b'], 1, 0, 1, true, 'J', true);
          $pdf->writeHTMLCell(80, '', 78, 84, $result2[$k]['a'], 1, 0, 1, true, 'J', true);    

          $pdf->writeHTMLCell(160, '', 19, 185, $qr_code, 1, 0, 1, true, 'J', true); 
          // Get the QR-code
          if($qr_code!='') {
            try{
                $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);
                $style = array(
                    'border' => 2,
                    'vpadding' => 'auto',
                    'hpadding' => 'auto',
                    'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
                    'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255)
                    'module_width' => 1, // width of a single module in points
                    'module_height' => 1 // height of a single module in points
                );
            $pdf->write2DBarcode('www.tcpdf.org', 'PDF417', 20, 195, 0, 30, $style, 'N');
            //$pdf->write1DBarcode($qr_code, 'C128', 18, 190, $width, 13, 0, $style, 'N');   
            }catch(Exception $eo) {  }
          }

          // Get the Bar-codes from the list 
          $style = array(
            'border' => 0,
            'vpadding' => 'auto',
            'hpadding' => 'auto',
            'fgcolor' => array( 0, 0, 0 ),
            'bgcolor' => false,
            'stretch' => 1, 'text' => true
          );
          $pdf->write1DBarcode('00112233449', 'EAN13', 25, 195 +40, $width, 13, 0, $style, 'N');      

        }
      } 

    }

    $pdf->Output('a4', 'I');

  }
```

Comment: Do u want to place the barcode on page footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place the **1D barcode** on page footer, then you may simply extend the `TCPDF` class:

```
public function testingAction() {

    require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

    class MYTCPDF extends TCPDF{

        public function Footer(){

            $barcode = $this->getBarcode();
            if( !empty( $barcode ) ){
                $style = array(
                    'border' => 0,
                    'vpadding' => 'auto',
                    'hpadding' => 'auto',
                    'fgcolor' => array( 0, 0, 0 ),
                    'bgcolor' => false,
                    'stretch' => 1
                );
                $this->write1DBarcode( $barcode, 'EAN13', 84, 4, 75, 13, 0, $style, 'N' );

            }

        }

    }

    $pdf = new MYTCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->setBarcode( date('Y-m-d H:i:s') );

}
```

## UPDATE

According to this quote from OP's comment

> I need to place it bottom of the page where i have some space

I will provide this snippet

```
public function testingAction() {

    require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
    $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 027');
    $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

    $params = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtagParameters(
        array(
            date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'C39', '', '', 80, 30, 0.4,
            array(
                'position'=>'S',
                'border'=>true,
                'padding'=>4,
                'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0),
                'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255),
                'text'=>true,
                'font'=>'helvetica',
                'fontsize'=>8,
                'stretchtext'=>4
            ),
            'N'
        )
    );

    $html = '';
    $html .= '<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="'.$params.'" />';
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
    $pdf->Output('my_file.pdf', 'I');

}
```

Comment: NOT - in the footer, i have a full-screen image as background, i need to place it bottom of the page where i have some space.

Comment: I am trying your code, but its failing to make the PDF.

Comment: This is an instruction. it does not output any content, as I dont know what your content is! you should change it to fit your needs. but this is the right way of inserting barcode in TCPDF footer. As you mentioned you want to put the barcode at the bottom of the page, I will add an UPDATE to my answer. please check in a minute

Comment: @YumYumYum Please check the UPDATE

Comment: Last code still giving me same ERROR. I tried this code that works, but why your code not working? http://paste.ubuntu.com/15177254/

Comment: The method itself, put the barcode at the current position, which you have less control on its positioning, whereas the `<tcpdf>` template tag is a way with more positioning control. Please try to put date into a variable and use that variable inside `$params` . also try to replace it with a simple string like `20160201` and check if the error exists

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15177569/ - could you please help, its working but when i add long string which i need to, then its again failing.

Comment: Barcode standards have a maximum available length. Please check [this](https://www.tec-it.com/en/support/knowbase/barcode-overview/linear2/Default.aspx)

Comment: OK - thanks. i have EDITED my working sample in my EDIT section. Now both works long or less anything i want.